# How to uniquely identify a set of records each time I write to SQL Server database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have scenario in an ASP.NET MVC application where I upload an Excel file with multiple records, I display them in a grid / table.

Inserting these records to the database, I validate them against a procedure, then I edit the errors and re-validate again.

How can I group records from a user upload to enable user to retrieve those specific records when they need to re-validate?

Example:

**User A** uploads and user B uploads, all records get written to the database, how can user A get his/her specific records fro that specific time and upload.

How can I manage that in an ASP.NET MVC application that writes to SQL Server database. I write the domain name of the user to the database on each upload, but what if a user uploads twice in a specific time-frame.

Basically what I am asking is how can I manage record state and make sure that users get the records that they have uploaded at that specific time. Using C#, ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework to write to the database.

Please see code below and please advise how I can make my application more flexible.

```
public ActionResult ValidateClaims()
{
        List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = TempData["supplierClaimsData"] as List<CleanSupplierClaim>;
        //db.CleanSupplierClaims.ToList();
        //(List<CleanSupplierClaim>)TempData["claimsResponse"];////
        //= new List<SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList>();
        CleanSupplierClaimData supplierClaimUplaod = new CleanSupplierClaimData();

        var sqlConnection = "data source=WMVSQL02;initial catalog=Embrace;integrated security=True;";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var claim in supplierClaimsData)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                    SqlDataReader reader;
                    cmd.CommandText = "CRM.Supplier_Claim_Upload";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Invoice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = claim.Line_Number;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = claim.Total_Claim;

                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    //cmd.CommandTimeout = 1;

                    conn.Open();
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        claim.ST_Key = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ST_Key"));
                        claim.Error_1 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Error1"));

                        string lineNumberDoesNotExist = "Error: Invoice line number does not exist";
                        if (claim.Error_1.StartsWith(lineNumberDoesNotExist))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        claim.Warning = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Warning"));
                        claim.Error_2 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Error2"));

                        var officialUserName = TempData["user"];

                        claim.Domain_Username = officialUserName.ToString();

                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        int nextNumber = rnd.Next();

                        if (claim.ST_Key != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(claim.Warning) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(claim.Error_1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(claim.Error_2))
                        {
                            db.GPClaimsReadyToImports.Add(new GPClaimsReadyToImport
                            {
                                Id = claim.Id,
                                ST_Key = claim.ST_Key,
                                Warning = claim.Warning,
                                Action = claim.Action,
                                Claim_Reference = claim.ClaimReference,
                                Currency = claim.Currency,
                                Error_1 = claim.Error_1,
                                Error_2 = claim.Error_2,
                                Line_Numebr = claim.Line_Number,
                                Total_Claim = claim.Total_Claim,
                                Domain_Username = claim.Domain_Username,
                                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                ImportFlag = true,
                                ReadyForImport = true
                            });

                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            db.CleanSupplierClaims.Add(new CleanSupplierClaim
                            {
                                Id = claim.Id,
                                ST_Key = claim.ST_Key,
                                Warning = claim.Warning,
                                Action = claim.Action,
                                ClaimReference = claim.ClaimReference,
                                Currency = claim.Currency,
                                Error_1 = claim.Error_1,
                                Error_2 = claim.Error_2,
                                Line_Number = claim.Line_Number,
                                Total_Claim = claim.Total_Claim,
                                Domain_Username = claim.Domain_Username,
                                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                ImportFlag = false,
                                ReadyForImport = false,
                            });
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: give them a transaction ID and write it to the database. It can be a GUID, a datetime stamp, some arbitrary number/string, whatever you want. You're basically just grouping records by some value.

Comment: Adding to @DrewJordan - you will need to write the ID into the view or add it to the url so that you will receive the ID as a parameter on the MVC action.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by adding a new table to your database, `UploadSession` (for example). The table represents a unique upload session made by a user.
This table will have an `ID` column (auto generated identity), a column for the user and a column for the time.
In your existing table, add an `UploadSessionID` column which will be a foreign key to the `ID` column in `UploadSession`.
When you upload the data, create a row in the `UploadSession` table, get back the generated ID, and assign it to all records you insert to the existing table.

When the user requests all the records he/she uploaded at a specific time, query the `UploadSession` table to find the matching session id, then query your existing table for all records matching that session id.